# How to merge two csv files with a different number of column and different class of column in R

Tags: r, csv, merge

I would merge two csv files but the problem is that they dont have the same number of column. The secund prblem is the column class. For example, each csv have a column called DATA but in the first csv this column is empty so it class is charactere adn in the secund csv the column is full so it class is date.

this is my code :

```
data_all <- list.files(
  path = "D:/Utilisateur/Desktop/STAGE/data2",
  pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE
)


for (i in 1:length(data_all)) {
  if (i == 1) {
    DATA1 <- read_csv(data_all[i])
    DATA2 <- read_csv(file = data_all[i + 1])
    ALL_DATA <- rbind(DATA1, DATA2)
  } else {
    DATA3 <- read_csv(data_all[i])
    ALL_DATA <- rbind(DATA3, ALL_DATA)
  }
}
dest_file <- file.path("data", "all_data.csv")
write.csv(ALL_DATA, dest_file)
```

When I use `rbind` to merge, I have the number comlumn issue and when I use `bind_rows` it's the class issue. (because there are not the same in the both case)

example of my data frames :

```
DATA 1

IN FILE,DATE,ID,TIME
azerty,22-06-2019,f7e,00:12
qsdfgh,12-02-2018,s5d,05:45

DATA2

IN FILE,DATE,ID
azerty,NA,f7e
qsdfgh,NA,s5d
```

So, why can I do to merge my two csv ?

Comment: Please show examples of your dataframes

Comment: It's done, I had examples.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. W e can use  `rbind.fill` from `plyr` package which allows to merge csv with different number of column